# How to find out if a file is a directory (optimal way)

Tags: c, winapi

I am working at an OS independent file manager, and I am having a problem with properly detecting if a file is a directory or not on Windows.
The `dirent` structure on windows doesn't appear to have a `DT_DIR` field, so I am using:

```
file_attributes=GetFileAttributes(ep->d_name);
if(file_attributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)files_list[i].is_dir=1;
else files_list[i].is_dir=0;
```

However, this is not always accurate, as some files are marked as directories (for example, pagefile.sys). Besides, `GetFileAttributes` is rather slow if you have a lot of files.

I also have a function:

```
int does_dir_exist(char *path)
{
DIR *dp_test;

dp_test = opendir(path);
if(dp_test)
    {
        return 1;
        closedir(dp_test);
    }

return 0;
  }
```

But this is pretty slow (won't be a good idea to do it on 10000 files).

Of course, I can combine both which would be pretty fast, but is there a better way?

P.S. For some reason can't format the code properly for the second function.

Comment: What makes you say that `GetFileAttributes` is slow. I'm far from convinced that you can find anything faster.

Comment: I find it hard to believe that some files (such as pagefile.sys) has the `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY` flag on. Perhaps the `GetFileAttributes` eventually returns you an error code -1, which has all bits set

Comment: I commented it out and it is much faster without it. And on Linux it is faster (since I don't have to do that). If you have like 2K files in a dir, and you did not call `GetFileAttributes` on them recently, it can take a few seconds.

Comment: Valdo, thanks, that was it! Please put that as an answer.

Comment: Yes, it's certainly true that a `nop` is pretty dardned fast but that doesn't mean that all programs can run as fast as `nop`.

Comment: What I meant was that the bulk of the time spent in parsing a directory and getting the files and stuff was spent in `GetFileAttributes`. It was even slower than `qsorting` the files.

Comment: I'm not sure why this is tagged `winapi` since `dirent` is not supported by Windows. Where are you getting it from? The native API is `FindFirstFile/FindNextFile` which returns a structure containing flags `dwFileAttributes`, and one of those flags is `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY`.

Comment: `dirent` is supported by gcc. The question is tagged as win32 because the dirent method does not allow for the IS_DIR method to find out if something is a dir or not, so obviously I'd have to use  awin32 function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `GetFileAttributes()`.  `opendir` and `closedir` are not going to faster (did you profile it?  Did you repeat your tests to avoid cache effects?).

Yes, `GetFileAttributes()` *is* accurate.  The reason you think it's failing is because when you try to get the attributes of `pagefile.sys`, it's failing and returning `INVALID_FILE_ATTRIBUTES`, which is `(DWORD)-1`.  When you test that with the `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY`, it returns true, because `-1` has every bit set in it.

How many files are you running this on?  Whatever function you use, this is going to be an I/O-bound operation, since in order to determine a file's attributes, the parent directory has to be read from disk (or the disk cache).

Comment: Yes, that was it, thanks. I do not use opendir/closedir for this purpose, it is just to determine somewhere else in the code if a directory exists or not (and it is multiplatform). The method I use is opendir/readdir to read the files, since it is multi patform.

Answer (score 1):

```
_wfinddata_t fd;
_wfindfirst
_wfindnext
_findclose
```

If you use those methods to determine the elements in a folder you get the GetFileAttributes result for free.

Comment: Thanks, but I want to keep most of my code as platform independent as possible. But will consider your suggestion if I have some spare time to modify that code.